# Multiple dictionary operations in one line

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a helper function to initialize a dictionary.  I then need to add additional items to the dictionary.  Is there any way I can consolidate it to one line?  Here is a test class to illustrate what I'm trying to achieve:

```
class Test:
    def get_dict(self):
        dict = self.initialize_dict()
        dict.update( { 'new_item' : 'Hello' } )
        return dict

    def initialize_dict(self):
        return { 'blah' : 10 }

test = Test()
print(test.get_dict())
```

If I add .update() to the end of self.initialize_dict() the dictionary returns None.  Any idea why None is returned when I string the operations together?  Is there some other dictionary operation I can use?  Just trying to make this code a little less verbose.

```
def get_dict(self):
    return self.initialize_dict().update( { 'new_item' : 'Hello' }
```

Comment: Why do you feel the need to make it into one line?  What do you think this will gain you?

Comment: Regarding to the `None` result, it is because the `update` method doesn't return anything, try this: `d1 = {};
print d1.update()`

Comment: @BrenBarn Just wanted to see if there was a way to initialize the dictionary and add a new item at once because it seemed like it should be possible.  After seeing mgilson's answer I would agree it is probably better suited as two lines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is there a way to consolidate it?  Yes:

```
dict({'blah': 10}, new_item='Hello')
```

However, there are constraints on the dictionaries you can create this way and generally, I think 2 lines is better.

Comment: Thanks.  After seeing your answer I would agree it is probably better as two lines.